# Best solution to communicate in Android

Tags: android, sockets, http, resources, communication

I want to create an Android app (my first one) with a friend. The main part of this app is about the communicatioon between two devices. Phone A needs to be able to send info to phone B and vice versa. My question is "*what's the best solution to establish this communication ?" ...

At the moment we are trying to do it with Sockets. One phone is the server and the other one the client and then they communicate. Problem is it doesnt seem to work as the client never reaches the server (time out). It may be because the IP address the client enters is the router address ...

The other solution would be to have an intermediate web server which communicates with phones throught Http. But we think it may consume a lot of internet connection. How can we know that ?

Please help us choose the best solution between these two or another one if you have an idea.

EDIT : I forget to mention that the two devices are not in the same local network so they need to communicate with internet.

Thanks.
Onyx

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend two ways:

1. The quickest way would be to solve this issue with a direct socket connection between the devices. Maybe it doesn't work in your case, because one of the phones is in a local network. Then you usually cannot access the ip from the outside, cause of the Network Adress Translation. So you simply should not connect with wifi and find out the IP-Adress of your device. Here is more Information: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Address_Translation

Maybe the following tutorial is helpful for you.
http://android-er.blogspot.co.at/2014/02/android-sercerclient-example-client.html

2. Depending on what exactly you want to achieve, you also can build a REST-Backend. You should not use this solution, if you need high performance and really fast communication. For building a REST-Backend i can recommend node.js and swagger, maybe you should take a look at this technologies.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. When you say "simply should not connect with wifi and find out the IP-Adress of your device" you mean connect with 3G so i can have my self IP address ?

Comment: Yes exactly. When you are inside a network, your IP-Adress from outside is different than the IP-Adress inside the network. That's because the router has exactly one IP-Adress for outgoing connectivity. Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bluetooth or Wifi-P2P if your devices support it. [Check here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html)

Your existing system will also work if you do it properly. For that you can give your code here.

Otherwise you can use UDP broadcast for server and client if they are in a local (possibly WiFi) network.